# calculate experience of employee

Tags: sql, sql-server

total count experience of employee and also display those employee which have greater than 5 year experience ...

Please help Me. 
Thank you in Advance.

```
SELECT tbl_Employee.EFirstName,
       tbl_Employee.EMiddleName,
       tbl_Employee.ELastName,
       tbl_Empl‌​oyee.EmployeeID, 
       tbl_BranchMaster.BranchName,
       tbl_DepartmentMaster.DepartmentName,
       tbl_StateMaster.‌​StateName,
       tbl_Employee.EmployeementDate,
       dbo.FN_Basic(tbl_Employee.EmployeeID) AS basic,
       YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(tbl_Employee.EmployeementDate) AS Age
FROM tbl_StateMaster 
INNER JOIN tbl_DepartmentMaster 
INNER JOIN tbl_EmployeeStructure 
INNER JOIN tbl_Employee ON tbl_EmployeeStructure.EmployeeID = tbl_Employee.EmployeeID 
INNER JOIN tbl_BranchMaster ON tbl_EmployeeStructure.BranchID = tbl_BranchMaster.BranchID 
                            ON tbl_DepartmentMaster.DepartmentID = tbl_EmployeeStructure.DepartmentID 
                            ON tbl_StateMaster.StateID =tbl_EmployeeStructure.StateID
```

Comment: Please post the complete SQL you tried, and indicate what's the problem with it.  Also, clarify if it's MySQL or SQL Server, because they have different syntax.

Comment: SELECT tbl_Employee.EFirstName,tbl_Employee.EMiddleName,tbl_Employee.ELastName,tbl_Employee.EmployeeID, tbl_BranchMaster.BranchName,tbl_DepartmentMaster.DepartmentName,tbl_StateMaster.StateName,tbl_Employee.EmployeementDate,dbo.FN_Basic(tbl_Employee.EmployeeID) AS basic,YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(tbl_Employee.EmployeementDate) AS Age

Comment: FROM tbl_StateMaster INNER JOIN
tbl_DepartmentMaster INNER JOIN
tbl_EmployeeStructure INNER JOIN tbl_Employee ON tbl_EmployeeStructure.EmployeeID = tbl_Employee.EmployeeID INNER JOIN tbl_BranchMaster ON tbl_EmployeeStructure.BranchID = tbl_BranchMaster.BranchID ON tbl_DepartmentMaster.DepartmentID = tbl_EmployeeStructure.DepartmentID ON tbl_StateMaster.StateID =tbl_EmployeeStructure.StateID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS employee;

CREATE TABLE employee(id INT , joining_date DATETIME);

INSERT INTO `employee` (`id`, `joining_date`) VALUES ('1', NOW()),('2',NOW() - INTERVAL 6 YEAR);

SELECT * FROM employee;
+------+---------------------+
| id   | joining_date        |
+------+---------------------+
|    1 | 2014-02-17 17:56:53 |
|    2 | 2008-02-17 17:56:53 |
+------+---------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

SELECT id,joining_date FROM employee WHERE DATEDIFF(DATE(NOW()),DATE(joining_date))/365 > 5;
+------+---------------------+
| id   | joining_date        |
+------+---------------------+
|    2 | 2008-02-17 17:56:53 |
+------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

You can also try

```
SELECT id,joining_date,DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(NOW())-TO_DAYS(joining_date)),'%Y')+0 AS YearsOfExp FROM employee WHERE DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(NOW())-TO_DAYS(joining_date)),'%Y')+0 > 5;
+------+---------------------+------------+
| id   | joining_date        | YearsOfExp |
+------+---------------------+------------+
|    2 | 2008-02-17 17:56:53 |          6 |
+------+---------------------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

For Better use of Indexes you can write it like

```
SELECT * FROM employee WHERE joining_date <= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -5 YEAR);
```

Comment: [DATEDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) will return the number of days difference, not the number of years, so in 6 days time both employees would be returned by your query. In addition using functions on a column makes the query not sargeable. A much better solution would be: `WHERE joining_date <= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -5 YEAR)` - [Demo on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/579094/2) (*Note the use of the index on joining date in the final query)*

Comment: I hope divide by 365 should work.

Comment: It would almost, although doesn't account for leap years. It is still not [sargable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) though. Where possible never use functions on columns where you can avoid it, instead use the function on constants (such as `NOW()`).

Comment: Added another one, Can you please have a look at that

Comment: Again, it works, but it is not a good approach, [as shown here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/579094/3), it still does not make use of any indexes on the date column.

Comment: Hey Help Me i also given table format